# Translate unicode to actual characters

Tags: python, unicode, lxml, codec

I am writing a file in Chinese:

```
<locale name="cmn-Hans">
    <title>&#22823;&#30333;&#40104; Jaws</title>
    <synopsis>&#30001;&#37329;&#20687;&#22870;&#23548;&#28436;&#21490;&#33922;&#33452;&#183;&#26031;&#30382;&#23572;&#20271;&#26684;&#25191;&#23548;&#65292;&#12298;&#22823;&#30333;&#40104;&#12299;&#26641;&#31435;&#20102;&#32039;&#24352;&#24748;&#30097;&#29255;&#30340;&#26631;&#20934;&#65292;&#24182;&#36805;&#36895;&#25104;&#20026;&#19968;&#31181;&#25991;&#21270;&#29616;&#35937;&#65292;&#27704;&#36828;&#25913;&#21464;&#20102;&#35266;&#20247;&#30340;&#30005;&#24433;&#32463;&#39564;&#12290;&#28626;&#28023;&#30340;&#33406;&#31859;&#25552;&#23567;&#38215;&#36973;&#21040;&#19968;&#26465;&#21361;&#38505;&#30340;&#22823;&#30333;&#40104;&#25915;&#20987;&#65292;&#38215;&#19978;&#30340;&#35686;&#38271;(&#27931;&#20234;&#183;&#34203;&#24503;)&#12289;&#24180;&#36731;&#30340;&#28023;&#27915;&#29983;&#29289;&#23398;&#23478;(&#29702;&#26597;&#24503;&#183;&#29790;&#20315;&#26031;)&#12289;&#32769;&#25104;&#30340;&#40104;&#40060;&#29454;&#20154;(&#32599;&#20271;&#29305;&#183;&#33831;)&#32852;&#25163;&#23637;&#24320;&#19968;&#22330;&#21361;&#24613;&#30340;&#20882;&#38505;&#65292;&#20934;&#22791;&#27585;&#28781;&#36825;&#21482;&#24618;&#20861;&#65292;&#20813;&#24471;&#23427;&#20877;&#24230;&#20260;&#20154;&#12290;&#20196;&#20154;&#38590;&#24536;&#30340;&#37197;&#20048;&#24102;&#26469;&#32431;&#31929;&#30340;&#24656;&#24807;&#65292;&#12298;&#22823;&#30333;&#40104;&#12299;&#33267;&#20170;&#20173;&#26159;&#30005;&#24433;&#21490;&#19978;&#26368;&#20855;&#24433;&#21709;&#21147;&#12289;&#26368;&#25187;&#20154;&#24515;&#24358;&#30340;&#20882;&#38505;&#30005;&#24433;&#20043;&#19968;&#12290;</synopsis>
</locale>
```

The file is written using `codecs` like so:

```
new_file = codecs.open(metadata_filepath, 'w', 'utf8')
new_file.write(u'''contents here''')
```

How would I get the file to look like the **actual** Chinese characters instead of the unicode characters:

```
<locale name="cmn-Hans">
    <title>大白鲨 Jaws</title>
    <synopsis>由金像奖导演史蒂芬·斯皮尔伯格执导，《大白鲨》树立了紧张悬疑片的标准，并迅速成为一种文化现象，永远改变了观众的电影经验。濒海的艾米提小镇遭到一条危险的大白鲨攻击，镇上的警长(洛伊·薛德)、年轻的海洋生物学家(理查德·瑞佛斯)、老成的鲨鱼猎人(罗伯特·萧)联手展开一场危急的冒险，准备毁灭这只怪兽，免得它再度伤人。令人难忘的配乐带来纯粹的恐惧，《大白鲨》至今仍是电影史上最具影响力、最扣人心弦的冒险电影之一。</synopsis>
</locale>
```

How would I get the file to print the Chinese characters (至今仍) instead of the Unicode representations (490;&#19978) ?

To get the initial contents I am using `etree.tostring(...)` from a Chinese xml file.

Comment: Which one is the version you want?  `&#30001;` or `由`?

Comment: try to open your file with `GB2312` encoding!

Comment: Please clarify: When you say "the actual Chinese characters instead of the unicode characters", what do you mean by "unicode characters"?  Also, when you say "why does it do that?" what exactly is the "that"?

Comment: It does that because that's how they're written.

Comment: @5gon12eder the one with 由

Comment: Check this: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html . Would this help: your_string.encode('utf-8') ?

Comment: One more question: Python 2 or Python 3?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, pass `encoding="utf-8"` to `ElementTree.tostring` and then open your file in binary mode.  In Python 3, you can instead pass `encoding="unicode"` to `ElementTree.tostring` and then open the file as you are.

Demo (Python 2):

```
>>> print(ET.tostring(tree, encoding="utf-8"))
<locale name="cmn-Hans">
    <title>大白鲨 Jaws</title>
    <synopsis>由金像奖导演史蒂芬·斯皮尔伯格执导，《大白鲨》树立了紧张悬疑片的标准，并迅速成为一种文化现象，永远改变了观众的电影经验。濒海的艾米提小镇遭到一条危险的大白鲨攻击，镇上的警长(洛伊·薛德)、年轻的海洋生物学家(理查德·瑞佛斯)、老成的鲨鱼猎人(罗伯特·萧)联手展开一场危急的冒险，准备毁灭这只怪兽，免得它再度伤人。令人难忘的配乐带来纯粹的恐惧，《大白鲨》至今仍是电影史上最具影响力、最扣人心弦的冒险电影之一。</synopsis>
</locale>

>>> print(ET.tostring(tree))
<locale name="cmn-Hans">
    <title>&#22823;&#30333;&#40104; Jaws</title>
<synopsis>&#30001;&#37329;&#20687;&#22870;&#23548;&#28436;&#21490;&#33922;&#33452;&#183;&#26031;&#30382;&#23572;&#20271;&#26684;&#25191;&#23548;&#65292;&#12298;&#22823;&#30333;&#40104;&#12299;&#26641;&#31435;&#20102;&#32039;&#24352;&#24748;&#30097;&#29255;&#30340;&#26631;&#20934;&#65292;&#24182;&#36805;&#36895;&#25104;&#20026;&#19968;&#31181;&#25991;&#21270;&#29616;&#35937;&#65292;&#27704;&#36828;&#25913;&#21464;&#20102;&#35266;&#20247;&#30340;&#30005;&#24433;&#32463;&#39564;&#12290;&#28626;&#28023;&#30340;&#33406;&#31859;&#25552;&#23567;&#38215;&#36973;&#21040;&#19968;&#26465;&#21361;&#38505;&#30340;&#22823;&#30333;&#40104;&#25915;&#20987;&#65292;&#38215;&#19978;&#30340;&#35686;&#38271;(&#27931;&#20234;&#183;&#34203;&#24503;)&#12289;&#24180;&#36731;&#30340;&#28023;&#27915;&#29983;&#29289;&#23398;&#23478;(&#29702;&#26597;&#24503;&#183;&#29790;&#20315;&#26031;)&#12289;&#32769;&#25104;&#30340;&#40104;&#40060;&#29454;&#20154;(&#32599;&#20271;&#29305;&#183;&#33831;)&#32852;&#25163;&#23637;&#24320;&#19968;&#22330;&#21361;&#24613;&#30340;&#20882;&#38505;&#65292;&#20934;&#22791;&#27585;&#28781;&#36825;&#21482;&#24618;&#20861;&#65292;&#20813;&#24471;&#23427;&#20877;&#24230;&#20260;&#20154;&#12290;&#20196;&#20154;&#38590;&#24536;&#30340;&#37197;&#20048;&#24102;&#26469;&#32431;&#31929;&#30340;&#24656;&#24807;&#65292;&#12298;&#22823;&#30333;&#40104;&#12299;&#33267;&#20170;&#20173;&#26159;&#30005;&#24433;&#21490;&#19978;&#26368;&#20855;&#24433;&#21709;&#21147;&#12289;&#26368;&#25187;&#20154;&#24515;&#24358;&#30340;&#20882;&#38505;&#30005;&#24433;&#20043;&#19968;&#12290;</synopsis>
</locale>
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same, +1.  This also works with [`ElementTree.write`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) which is probably preferable here.

Comment: @zwol This works with `print` but when I try and write to my document it gives me encoding errors. Any idea what causes that?

Comment: @Hockey127 You need to open the file in binary mode if you're using `encoding="utf-8"` on the `ET.tostring` or `ET.write` operations.